# iOS Dev: Certificates and hiring a freelancer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have hired a freelancer to build an app for me. I have an individual dev account to which I have added him as a technical user. He has requested either that I send him distribution and development certs plus a provisioning profile OR to make him an admin role in iTunes Connect.
Should I create certificates with my name/email and send them to him? Or with his name/email? Or should I just make him an admin? What is the best/safest course of action? This is just for testing purposes and I will be receiving the source code upon project completion.
Totally new to iOS dev and have been scrounging around the web for a definitive answer. Sorry if this is rudimentary!
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming problems.

Comment: Thanks. It's about iOS app development and my first experience on SO. Just curious, and not trying to sound snarky at all, what is the itunesconnect tag for if not procedural questions like these?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add him as a Admin at all. If he has a free developer account you can sent him a request to add to your developer account team and can create a development and distribution profile from which developer can download. For certificate request developer need to send the request from him Mac and can download it from developer.apple.com.

For other option i am not sure if it will work because from latest XCode environment developer account needs to be added in Xcode but give it a try.

Other option if you don't at all want to give access to your developer account will be. Create and download the developer and distribution profile and share it with Freelancer.
For Certificate you would be requiring a Mac. Below is a process of creating a certificate:
http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/generating-your-development-certificate/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Now goto your KeyChain access and can see your certificate there:

[image]

Right Click your certificate and export "iPhone Developer..." or "iPhone Distribution.." . Save it to your desktop. It will be a .p12 file and will ask for password while saving.
Share this .p12 file with the freelancer along with password. Share both Developer and Distribution certificate.

So now your freelancer has both Developer and Distribution certificate and provisional profile.

Answer (score 0):

Since he is not the one that will be submitting the app to AppStore, then he should not be an admin. So the admin account is with your credentials. 
Usually, if he is an iOS freelancer, most likely he already has an Apple account. So after he creates a certificate signing request, you should generate a development certificate for him, in order to test on real devices - that is, you must add his user to your created team.

However, the certificates-accounts process is not so easy, so I'd recommend you to also read: http://escoz.com/blog/demystifying-ios-certificates-and-provisioning-files/ .

Comment: Thanks! Although I read through that article and was still unsure how to apply it to a freelancer situation. He does have a dev account but Users and Roles would not allow me to add another dev account so he provided an alternate email to use. I have added him as a user assigned with the technical role with that email. So to clarify: I ask him to generate a certificate signing request and send it to me then I create a dev cert for him? Does using my name or his matter in this scenario?
Much appreciated!